# If else function not consistently working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I cannot get this if/else to replace more than one row of of the column at a time. I have tried

```
spreadSheet.getRange(2, 38, 4000)

spreadSheet.getRange(2, 38, spreadSheet.getLastRow()-1)
```

and

```
spreadSheet.getRange(2, 38, sheet.getMaxRows())
```

It's not returning anything if it's not set up like below (and that only returns one cell.

```
function calculateHitPoints(){
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
    var setHP = spreadSheet.getRange(2, 38).getValues();

    if(setHP == "Fighter"){
        spreadSheet.getRange(2, 38).setValue("14");
    }
    else if(setHP == "Ranger"){
        spreadSheet.getRange(2, 38).setValue("13");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please consider explaining in more detail what you want to accomplish. It's not clear, based on the information you provided. It would probably be worth taking a look at the official docs for `getValue()`, `getValues()`, `setValue()`, `setValues()` and the different `getRange`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're getting row 2 in column 38. That's why it's only getting that cell only.

**getRange()** has multiple implementations you can refer to this links here.

[Sheet.getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column)

[Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows)

[Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)

[Sheet.getRange(a1notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

Comment: yes, but the numRows, etc aren't working.